# Nexus: rebuild metadata using the REST API witout being an admin

Tags: maven, jenkins, ant, build, nexus

I am trying to rebuild the metadata for a particular artifact in Nexus. I want to use the REST API:

```
DELETE /service/local/metadata/repositories/myRepository/content
```

So far it is working well. However, I need the `Nexus Administrator Role` for the command to work. Since I am building in a large environment with lots of users using Ant (which is automated by Jenkins) I would love to use another user, possibly just dedicated to refreshing the metadata, with only the required privileges (but it seems like that privilege is admin). I don't want my `build.xml` to have admin credentials!

I am thinking of some workarounds such as calling a separate Jenkins job with hidden credentials, or add a post-build step in the build job... It all just sounds too ugly.

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Thanks
Phil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They need the "Rebuild Maven Metadata" privilege.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I needed. And then from Ant I call the Nexus REST API to rebuild the Maven metadata. Thanks @rseddon.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Mask+Passwords+Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Mask+Passwords+Plugin) to hide the passwords in the job, and pass it as a parameter to your ant script.

Comment: That helps, but I was wondering if there's a way to do this from Ant.

Comment: If you want to do this from your ANT script you might as well do it on your Nexus. you can definitely create a user with the right privileges: https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/security-privileges.html